# Display data in tabular form

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have few details in database in below format

```
startdate   EndDate week_no vSalesConsultant    totalsale   points
5/28/2018   6/3/2018    Wk1 Test1                   10       10
5/28/2018   6/3/2018    Wk1 Test2                   6        10
6/4/2018    6/10/2018   Wk2 Test1                   13       10
6/4/2018    6/10/2018   Wk2 Test3                   12       10
```

My desired ASP.NET table format output is:

```
        wk1 wk2
Test1   10  10
Test2   10  0
Test3   0   10
```

Please suggest i have tries table type but not succeed.

Comment: What did you try and what didn't work as you intended? Please add your code here so we can see what might be wrong? Is this MVC or web forms -application?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to sum the points per week,
You can condition it with a case when statement, and group by the sales consultant

```
select 
    vSalesConsultant , 
    sum(case when week_no = 'Wk1' then points else 0 end) as Wk1,
    sum(case when week_no = 'Wk2' then points else 0 end) as Wk2
from  t
group by vSalesConsultant
order by vSalesConsultant
```

Comment: I thought on it but weeks may crease or decrease based on dates we give.

Comment: you got several options: 52 weeks per year = add 50 more case statements. Honestly, that's not so bad, I've seen worst. another option is to load the data as it is, and do the aggregation in the application layer via c#